# Rice meme simulation

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to simulate the "rice challenge" that is the latest meme with them kids, see [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5cDU2sLbmw) for a fun example.

This is my best result so far:

[image]  (Video: https://i.imgur.com/KxlzB84.mp4)

which isn't quite there yet.

Any general advice on how to approach this? A particle system is the obvious solution but I'm struggling to make it work.

Comment: Please do not use external links in the question if at all possible. Describe the rice challenge, screen shoot your results, or maybe use blend-exchange.com to share your blend file.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I tried to embed the gif/video but I don't have enough rep, so perhaps someone else could edit it in for me. (If .mp4 cannot be embedded, [here is a .gif](https://i.imgur.com/SPHZK9v.gif)). Y'know, a gif is worth a thousand pictures...

Comment: Try converting the particle system, and parenting it to the object. Then delete the particle system.

Answer (score -1):

here the "long story short" - so i assume you have some experience with BLender.

1. make a text
2. convert to mesh
3. remesh modifier
4. add particles, tweak some settings
5. add plane with collision, tweak some settings
6. rotate text mesh so that is lies horizontal on the plane
7. animate the plane with location movement to positive z axis and some rotation on x axis
8. enjoy your rice challenge animation

Result: https://youtu.be/wAtmM0UhLQo

Video tutorial: https://youtu.be/sz-6LapA_yk

Comment: This is great, thanks! I really don't understand the downvotes, could someone please explain what's going on here?

Comment: thank you, you are welcome. Well....you will learn that some people just want the official rules to be kept...they are not really interested in people helping people, but their main focus is playing sheriff. Give people power...and they will misuse it ;)